# Query to display row after 1 pm

Tags: mysql

How to fetch all rows from table where time is greater than 13:00 i.e. 1PM

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `time` >="13:00";
```

Comment: What is the data type of time column? If it is time then your query should work just fine.

Comment: What data you have in ```time``` column? Show sample data for it and what issues you are facing with this query.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gWH895r5c2GC3nccoPFMAK/0

Comment: Please don't use double quotes for string literals, because they can be interpreted as something else.

Comment: thank you @all after changing varchar to time solve my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a `datetime` field you could do this (I'm assuming here as you haven't specified):

```
create table tester(`id` int(6), `name` varchar(50), `datetest` datetime);

insert into tester(`id`,`name`,`datetest`)
values(1, 'n1', '2018-12-20 09:00:00'),
(2, 'n2', '2018-12-20 10:00:00'),
(3, 'n3', '2018-12-20 13:10:00'),
(4, 'n4', '2018-12-20 14:00:00');

select * from tester 
where TIME(datetest) > '13:00'
```